# Showing that the function $f(x,y) =\frac{{x^7+x^4y^2+x^2y^4+y^8}}{{x^6+x^4|y|+|y|^7}}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to show that the function $f(x,y) =\frac{{x^7+x^4y^2+x^2y^4+y^8}}{{x^6+x^4|y|+|y|^7}}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

I know how to show that a function is discontinuous (by showing that two paths converge to different limits) but I don't quite know how to do the opposite. I've tried solving the limit, but that's getting me nowhere. Could I possibly use epsilon and delta? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And how much is $f(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not continuous $f(x,0)=x\to 0$ but $f(x^3,x^2)=\frac{x^7+2x^2+1}{x^4+2}\to \frac 12$

Note: I found it via Taylor expansion at $y$ fixed $f(x,y)=y+\frac{x^2}{y^3}+O(x^4?)$, thus the idea of trying $y^3=x^2$ so that this second term is finite.

Comment: how did you do the taylor expansion?

Comment: basically only consider $\frac{y^8+x^2y^4}{y^7}$ and ignore terms in $x^4,x^6,x^7$ hastily (it doesn't respect any standard), was just to give me an idea of what to expect.

Comment: okay that makes sense, thanks! but where does the O(x^6) come from? why is it x^6 and not just x?

Comment: also what does having a finite term give us? is it helpful in calculating the limit? i don't really see it :/

Comment: We are trying to prove $f$ is not continuous (i.e has some directional limit different from $0$). By taking $x^2/y^3\sim k$ constant I hope that I would reach that goal, since all other terms a priori go to zero, I'm left with this $k$. Then I plug $f(x^3,x^2)$ and now do a forthright calculation to verify this is the case (keep in mind that it may not have worked). I'm just trying to show you how to get hunches, not a guarantee to work, but when the verification works, exercise is done!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f(0,0)=0$

$$\frac{{x^7+x^4y^2+x^2y^4+y^8}}{{x^6+x^4|y|+|y|^7}}=$$ $$
x\frac{x^6}{x^6+x^4|y|+|y|^7}+|y| \frac{x^4|y|}{x^6+x^4|y|+|y|^7}
+\frac{x^2y^4}{x^6+x^4|y|+|y|^7}+|y|\frac{|y|^7}{x^6+x^4|y|+|y|^7}$$

The first, second and fourth fractions are bounded above by 1 and below by 0.

Maybe you can try to look for a good bound for the third one